# Directly Make Webview in Segment back to Home Page

Tags: ios, swift

My back button success let the web page in webview can back to previous. However, because i am using Segment to display webview. Now my app is displaying like this, when user open that page, it will display first segment first, when i click second segment, it will go second segment's webview. The result should like that when i click back button, it will not back to first segment's webview, it should directly back to application home page. If understand my question, please help me and sorry for my bad english.

Code:

Button Back:

```
@IBAction func back(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if(webview.canGoBack)
    {
        webview.goBack()


    }else{
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    }
        }
```

When open the page, will display first segment webview code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: "https://www.facebook.com")
    webview.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))
    webview.scalesPageToFit = true
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Segment Webview:

```
@IBAction func Segment(_ sender: Any) {
    if Segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0{
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.facebook.com")
        webview.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))
         webview.scalesPageToFit = true

    }
    if Segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com")
        webview.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))
        webview.scalesPageToFit = true
    }
    if Segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")
        webview.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))
         webview.scalesPageToFit = true
}
}
```