# How to scroll the webview in Tab Fragment down

Tags: android, xml, webview, fragment

My Webview is implemented in Tab Fragment. I would like to scroll web view to the bottom in fragment. Now i can't  scroll down the webview in fragment. I'm using android studio to develop it. Below is my code:

Fragment XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="371dp"
    android:layout_height="516dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-12dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-3dp" />
   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Activty:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<include layout="@layout/fragment_schedule" />
```

Comment: please reply me, thank a lot

Comment: why you can't scroll it ? what are the errors you facing ? any crashes ? what have you tried so far ?

Comment: @Umair, no crashes, can scroll ,but cannot scroll to the bottom, mean it will scroll down but will not scroll until the bottom of website.

Comment: have you tried using relativeLayout instead of constraintLayout ?

Comment: @Umair i solved already , replace with relative layout and add android:paddingbottom in relative layout, thanks

Comment: can i add it as an answer and you accept it ? ;)

Comment: Alright , i accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright try using **RelativeLayout** it will be shown full. You are facing this problem due to constraintLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom= "5dp">

<WebView
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="371dp"
android:layout_height="516dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-12dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-3dp" />
 </RelativeLayout >
```

Comment: Welcome. Ur answer really help me, and can you help me also in this question? Still don't have feedback. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47407124/directly-make-webview-in-segment-back-to-home-page

Comment: @MollyMolly I have no expertise in IOS bro. But as far as i understood the problem you are finishing your segment on starting of second segment, and if not you have to implement your logic on back press. Again this is normally what happens in android. No idea about IOS maybe same is the case there.

Answer (score 0):

@Umair answer pointed me int the right direction but it missed a point. I did not have to change to relative layout to fix it, my webview was throwing a warning, that it is not correctly constrained (see the red underline)

[image]

After I changed width and height to

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp" />
```

the problem got fixed right away. Now it is possible that this problem shows up only in fragments but this is one way to fix it.